# Get HTML id of Html.TextBoxFor field

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to get generated client-side ID for ASP.NET MVC controls in Javascript?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

Comment: [NameExtensions.IdFor<TModel, TProperty> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: By your question I thought you want to access the id in your javascript and not in the view using html helper!!

Comment: I will utilize this helper to pass id into javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Html.IdFor(m => m.Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are named after the property that is used to bind them, in your example, the textbox will have an ID of 'Name', unless you are in a repeating section.