# How to get the default id being generated by TextBoxFor in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add some javascript that needs to have the id of input being generated by TextBoxFor helper.

I do not want to set the id, just want to know if it is possible to know the id from ModelMetaData.

I don't want to parse the generated string and find the id by parsing.

I have looked at this post [Get HTML id of Html.TextBoxFor field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632587/get-html-id-of-html-textboxfor-field) problems is I can't use `@Html.IdFor(m => m.Name)` as this is in custom helper method :

```
public static MvcHtmlString TimePickerFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, string>> expression)
```

Comment: The `id` generated by `TextBoxFor()` (and all other helpers that generate form controls) is based on the name of the property and you can get it using the `GenerateIdFromName()` method of `HtmlHelper`. Or you can use the `@Html.IdFor()` method. But its not clear what your trying to do here.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Updated the question, Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Your edit suggest you might be trying to output a `<script>` tag in the helper which you definitely should not be doing

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Now that is interesting, yes, absolutely, why is it bad thing? thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : should I make a second helper? How does one make javascript tags that have code/data related to a rendering of TextBoxFor?

Comment: Inline scripts - [not good](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/). Possible duplicate scripts - bad. Just use the `TextBoxFor()` method and add a class name (say `class="timepicker"`) and then create a script `$('.timepicker').attachYourPlugin()` (and that script can go in an external js file/bundle)